# Strang: Simple Calculus Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm looking at Gilbert Strang's introductory calculus textbook "Calculus".
https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/resources/Strang/Edited/Calculus/Calculus.pdf.

In chapter 1, fig 1.5, Strang illustrates what happens when you alter the function f(t) = 2t + 1. He shows the following equations along with two similar graphs, the second shifted downward.

*f*(*t*) = 2*t* + 1

*f*(*t*) - 2 = 2*t* - 1

I realize that taking the first equation and subtracting 2 from the RHS alone will nudge the graph down 2 tics, but he's done it to both sides. Shouldn't this result in the same function, and the same graph? My only guess is that maybe he forgot to  relabel the axes?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOtXF.png

Comment: $f(t)-2=(2t+1)-2=2t-1$, or am I misinterpreting your query?

Answer (score 1):

If you rename

$$g(t) := f(t) -2$$

then you have the function $g(t) = 2t - 1$ which is what he illustrated.

If he would write $f(t) = 2t - 1$ then it would be ambiguous because you would label two different objects with the same name. This could lead to the wrong perception that

$$2t - 1 = 2t + 1$$

i.e.

$$-1 = +1$$

which is obviously not true.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you write

$$f(t)-2=(2t+1)-2,$$ $f$ is still the same function.

But the author shows

$$g(t):=f(t)-2=2t-1$$ next to $f(t)$.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. A label like the one you wrote *g(t*) would have been helpful.

Comment: @tupben: the label says $f(t)-2$ (vs. $f(t)$ on the left).